# How do I prevent Squid from caching HTML pages with the text/vnd.wap.wml MIME type?

Tags: squid, cache

We have a cluster of Squid servers at the front-lines for a large website, and we occasionally receive reports from QA/users that some pages use MIME types not supported by the browser (so they will be forced to download the file versus browsing the page).

The issue is that these pages have been cached with the text/vnd.wap.wml MIME type. In order to fix it, I have to purge them manually using squidclient, and then browse to the page with a normal browser.

I'm fairly confident this is caused by BlackBerry clients being the first to hit these pages, which forces Squid to cache the pages with the incorrect MIME type.

How can I prevent these pages from being cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to adopt one of the no-caching methods on the server-side... but you can setup an ACL & deny caching on it... i.e.

```
acl NOCACHE rep_mime_type text/vnd.wap.wml
no_cache deny NOCACHE
```

(I think it's rep_mime_type ... might be req_mime_type...)